# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "cebra"?

Tags: etimología, palabras-raras, animales

La etimología que da el Diccionario de la lengua en la entrada  [cebra](https://dle.rae.es/cebra) es:

> Del ant. *ezebra* 'onagro', y este quizá del lat. equifĕrus 'caballo salvaje'.

El problema es que esta palabra, **ezebra**, no aparece en ninguno de los diccionarios accesibles a través del NTTLE y, consultado el CORDE, solo figuran 10 casos (en 5 documentos) de **ezebra**, todos anteriores al siglo XIV, lo que me hace dudar de esa etimología. Si es correcta, ¿cómo se explica el salto desde **equiferus** hasta ***cebra***?

Comment: Según lo que encontré y que pongo en la respuesta es Equiferus => enzebro => zebro/cebro => cebra

Pero el salto de equiferus a enzebro me parece muy largo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En [este artículo](https://sciencepress.mnhn.fr/sites/default/files/articles/pdf/az2015n1a2.pdf) repiten la misma idea, con referencias que no he perseguido demasiado ya que son de revistas o diccionarios que no me han resultado de fácil obtención.

> Philologists concede that the etymological evolution originally
> turned the Latin term equus ferus (lit., “wild horse”) into
> equiferus, and it was from this name that the words ezebro and/or
> enzebro derived (da Silveira 1948; Malkiel 1985; Corominas & Pascual
> 1989). Such consensus finds no discrepancies as of this writing, and
> it is from it that philologists such as Lief (2006) and Pascual Barea
> (2008) conclude that the equiferus and the zebro are synonymous. On
> the issue of the origin of the word zebra, Malkiel (1985) lamented
> that several etymological treatises “outside of the hispano-portuguese
> corner” maintained the myth of an African origin for the term without
> any reliable evidence to support it.The equivalence between the words
> zebro and onager, on the other hand, was established through the far
> more conten-tious way of translating the Latin onager as zebra, zebro
> or any of its derivatives in old romance tongue (e.g., in modern
> parlance, zebra/o in Portuguese and cebra/o in Spanish). Such a
> debatable equivalence may lie at the root of the taxonomical identity
> problem of the zebro

Estas son las referencias

- Malkiel Y. 1985. — Carolina Michaëlis de Vasconcelos forgotten sketch of an unfinished monograph on E(n)-zebra “Wild donkey”. Boletim de Filologia 30: 1-11.
- Silveira J.  Sa 1948. — Estudos sobre o vocabulário português (Formas, sentidos, prosódia, origens). Zevro. Zebra. Revista Portuguesa de Filólogia 2: 220-247.
- Corominas I. & Pascual J. 1989. — Diccionario Crítico Etimológico Castellano e Hispánico. Vol. 2. CE-F. Ed. Gredos, Madrid, 986 p.
- Lief E. a. 2006. — Syincope in Spanish and Portuguese: The Diachrony of Hispano-Romance phonotactics. Partial Fulfilment of the Requirements for the Degree of Doctor of Philosophy, Faculty of the Graduate School, Cornell University, New York, 351 p.
- Pascual Barea J. 2008. — Razas y empleos de los caballos de Hispania según los textos griegos y latinos de la antigüedad, in Santamaría M. T. (ed.), La transmisión de la ciencia desde la Antigüedad al Renacimiento. Ediciones de la Universidad de Castilla-La Mancha, Cuenca: 117-202.

Answer (score 0):

Las fuentes antiguas medievales son diversas y muy confusas, no hay ningún tipo de unanimidad, más bien todo lo contrarío. Así tenemos algunas noticias que nos hablan que la zebra es una especie de abra montesa, un tipo de mula salvaje e igualmente se hablan de burros y caballos salvajes que son capaces de relinchar, pero en general los aspectos quedan muy difusos e indefinidos.

Pequeño resumen de fuentes antiguas;

- S.XII "Encebra, bestia con pelaje acebrado, más grandes que el ciervo, con orejas largas". Libro del Thesoro
- S. XIII "coyros de zeuros". Portazgo de Beja
- S. XIII "Mando que todo aquel que moviere venado primero, con sus aves, puerco ciervo, enzebro o libre o conejo, o perdiz, o todos los otros, sean suyos;..."
- S. XIV "X cabritos en pelambre y una cerbuna" (SERRANO SANZ, Inventarios, II, 553)
- S. XIV A un "caçador de mont" se compran una çervia y un cabró munter, por 35 ss. (DOÑATE, Salarios, 469).

Desde el punto de vista etimológico, la palabra cebra/zebra esta conectada con la palabra "**cierva**". La variantes encontradas al respecto de los *ciervos* son;

- Ciervos: cierbos, ceruos, cieruo, cervum, cervi, ceruus, cerbuna, çerbuno, çerbuna cerbins, cers, çerf, cerf, çervos, Çervas çervu, çervia.

En los tiempos antiguos, antes de que existiera una división de los cérvidos(*Cervidae*), en los que se incluyen distintos tipos, era muy común la confusión, de hecho hoy en día persiste en muchas ocasiones esa misma confusión. En términos generales las especies más grandes de cérvidos, como otros grandes herbívoros, poseen una configuración similar a un caballo, de aquí la propia confusión, mientras que las más pequeñas suelen ser más pequeñas y rechonchas.

Esto indica, y entra dentro de lo posible, que la Zebra/enzebra fuere un tipo de la familia Cervidae.

En la Península Ibérica se considera que hay dos subespecies de ciervo, el *Cervus elaphus hispanicus*, por lo general de menor tamaño y localizado en el suereste ibérico y el *Cervus elaphus hispanicus*, de mayor tamaño y distribuido en el resto de territorio.

Esta propia diferencia entre estas dos subespecies de ciervo puede que hayan propiciado la confusión. De esta manera, y desde mi punto de vista, la palabra "*Çervas*" por metonimia, esta claro que es Cebra/Cevra para referirse a la especie de Ciervo/Cierva con características superiores y que posteriormente se llevará al ámbito africano.

Espero haber contribuido.

Diego M.